# how to put the data from kafka together

Tags: java, apache-kafka

1. For example, we want to get a lot of people's information, but this information is scattered and released into **Kafka**, and then use Java to consume kafka, you can get this piece of data .
2. Every time you get a consumer can get a How can the data be assembled in real time?
3. Combine the assembled data and post it to **redis**.

Comment: This appears to be "How do I use Kafka" question. In which case, you should probably start from sources closer to the service: read some tutorials, library pitch and documentation. Ask here if you have a specific question. Refer to [What is on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page for details.

Comment: It seems you want to use some streaming technology like apache storm to process the kafka data in real time and push to other store like redis. Try looking up for some realtime computation system like 'storm' or 'spark' and integrate with kafka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a stream processing solution, such as [Kafka Streams](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/), [KSQL](https://www.confluent.io/blog/ksql-open-source-streaming-sql-for-apache-kafka/), Spark Streaming, Flink, etc. Which you use depends on your preference and its fit for your particular requirement. For example,

- if you want to write with Java, you can use Kafka Streams, Spark Streaming etc.
- If you want to just use SQL, you can use KSQL.
- If you want to use Python, you use Spark Streaming, and so on.

Any good stream processing solution will work on a **per-event basis** and thus as data arrives it can be processed & enriched (assuming this is what you mean by "assembled in realtime).

Use Kafka Connect to stream data from Kafka to Redis. [See here](https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/) for a list of connectors, or just search Google.